# Drupal Search API Solr - Long strings

Tags: string, search, drupal, solr, full-text-search

I am using Search API Solr (Solr v4.9.0) for my Drupal Search. A customer just informed us that they found out that Solr does not show search results for strings that are longer then 15 characters.

The weired thing is, that we also use Search API Autocomplete in this project and all the long strings like for example "dampfschifffahrtsgesellschaft" are shown as a suggestion for the user when they start typing characters. But after selecting the string from the autocomplete suggestion, the searched term cant be found by Solr on the search result page.

It works without any problems for all strings with less then 15 characters. Someone got an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this was my own configuration fault ... I added part word search using this filters:

```
    <!-- Word Part Search Filter: -->
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" side="front"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" side="back"/>
```

As the maxGramSize was limited to 15 it couldnt work... I raised it up to 30 so now its working without any problems.